# extra spaces in report - Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

Good Day. I hope everyone is well and safe. I am writing a report that is counting the number of times an event occurs, however when I run the report, it has a lot of extra spaces in it. I have attached a sample of the output. I have tried playing with cell padding, and table spacing, just cannot figure it out. Hoping one of the brilliant people here could offer a suggestion. It seems like the number of results is influencing the number of spaces, but I don't know what I don't know.

Again thank you for your support.

Thank you.

[Sample number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bU0.png)

[Sample number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u6qE.png)

[report builder screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/534V5.png)

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppoeF.png)

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66kut.png)

Comment: You'll probably need to show the report design to get any real help, but I would suspect that either `1.` you have a details row group that you don't need or `2.` your lowest row group is grouping by too many columns.

Comment: I added the report items from the designer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 2 bit so f info that might be the most useful are not shown. A sample of the data that gets returned from your dataset, and the row group panel (under the main designer window) will be useful. Also, on you report design screen shot, select the tablix so the row group lines are shown in the left column and update the image.